# runscript executed multiple times for @Autowired jdbcTemplate and h2 in-memory database

Tags: spring-mvc, h2

I've inherited a project and am trying to get a set of integration tests running against an in-memory h2 database. In order for them to pass some tables, relationships and reference data needs creating.

I can see the problem in that the script referenced in `RUNSCRIPT` is being executed multiple times and therefore generating `Index "XXX_IDX" already exists` errors and other violations. So is there a way to force the script to only be run once or do I need a external database? It seems that the script is run on every connection which I assume is [**by design**](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection).

**properties file**

```
my.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:my_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;MVCC=TRUE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/create-tables-and-ref-data.sql'
```

**XML config**

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${my.datasource.url}"/>
    <!-- other properties for username, password etc... -->
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

**many Java classes in the following pattern**

```
@Component
public class SomethingDAOImpl implements SomethingDAO {
  @Autowired
  public SomethingDAOImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }
}

@Component
public class SomethingElseDAOImpl implements SomethingElseDAO {
  @Autowired
  public SomethingElseDAOImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }
}
```

With the default bean scope being singleton I thought this would just work, but I guess i'm missing something. Also, if I switch to an real Oracle instance that already has the tables and reference data set-up, the tests all pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an alternative approach, as I could not write the SQL in a way that could be reapplied without error.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="myDataSource" enabled="true" ignore-failures="ALL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:create-and-alter-tables-first-then-add-test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans>
```

which is executed once at context initialization.

*Note: other namespaces and beans omitted for brevity.*

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, it is possible to write the SQL script so that no exceptions are thrown:

```
create table if not exists test(id int, name varchar(255));
create index if not exists test_idx on test(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had already made some changes like that but it seems that I can't do the same thing for sequences easily in Oracle. I did search for a "create or replace sequence" first :-) I would like to avoid, if possible, re-writing all of the existing SQL so an "initialize database once" solution would be preferable.