# Spring boot h2 unit test setup runs the import script twice

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Below is my Test file for my DAO class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo.bu"})
@ContextConfiguration(
        locations = "/META-INF/test-config.xml")
@SpringBootTest(classes={MyDao.class})
@Transactional
public class MyDaoTest {

    @Autowired MyDao myDao;

    @Test
    public void getAllDataSet() {
        List<ProductEntity> list = myDao.getAllData();
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
}
```

While the test-config.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

   <bean id="workflowhost" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
              <value>com.foo.bu.dao</value>
              <value>com.foo.bu.entity</value>
         </array>
      </property>
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/test/resources/data.sql'" />
      <property name="username" value="" />
      <property name="password" value="" />
   </bean>  

   <bean id="JpaTxnManager_workflowhost" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="workflowhost" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
   <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="JpaTxnManager_workflowhost"/>

   <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

My data.sql basically contains sql script which creates a bunch of tables as well as inserts mock records into the tables.

When i run my test file, i get exception related to "Unique index or primary key violation" for the sql script which is trying to insert records. The only way this can happen is if the script is executed twice. I'm not sure why this is happening. I circumvented this issues for my CREATE TABLE script by adding the clause `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

I went through the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html which speaks about setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto:none` if we didn't want Hibernate to create the schema. I've disabled that as well.

Can someone please help me understand why would the script run twice?

Comment: Found the solution using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070997/runscript-executed-multiple-times-for-autowired-jdbctemplate-and-h2-in-memory-d